# How to mock Axios get response with jest

Tags: node.js, axios, jestjs

How do I mock an axios get response? This test is failing with the following error:

```
Error: expect(jest.fn()).toHaveReturnedWith(expected)

Expected: {"test": "test"}
Received: {}

Number of returns: 1
```

This is the test I'm running:

```
jest.mock('axios');
const axios = require('axios');

describe('GET /searchLocation', () => {
    it('should return mock object', () => {
        const mockResp = { test: 'test' };
        axios.get.mockResolvedValue(mockResp);
        axios.get('/');
        expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/'); //passes
        expect(axios.get).toHaveReturnedWith(mockResp); //fails
    });
});
```

Comment: It didn't return `mockResp`, it returned a _promise_ of it. But there isn't much point in asserting what it returns anyway, it returns what you just configured it to.

Comment: @jonrsharpe the assert was just me trying to validate that the mock was working and not meant as a real test of anything. You're right on the promise, thanks :) I was chasing a red herring my failures are elsewhere!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think replacing this:

```
  axios.get.mockResolvedValue(mockResp);
```

With this:

```
  axios.get = jest.fn(() => mockResp);
```

Should help you.

P.S.: this call `expect(axios.get)` won't wait for promise to resolve.